# Normal blend mode math

Tags: algorithm, color, color-science, blending

I have one question.
How to calculate source color after blending operation.
For example. I have

1 - Background color (r-115, g-94, b-67, a-1)

2 - Foreground color above background color, which blended with normal blend mode (r-255, g-255, b-255, a-0.2)

3 - Result color - with this operation will be (r-143, g-126, b-105, a-1)

Question - How to calculate Background color with given Foreground color and Result color?

Images below

1 - Background color

[image]

2 - Foreground color. White with alpha 0.2. Can't see clearly, because this color have alpha 0.2
[image]

3 - Result color.

[image]

All this operation made in Photoshop

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.